# Regex Non Printable Character Plus Currency Symbols

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I want to match non printable character plus currency symbols the following matches non printable, how to add expectations for currency symbols?

```
$str = preg_replace('/[[:^print:]]/', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\p{Sc}` pattern matches currency symbols, you just need to place it into the *negated character class* (or *bracket expression* in POSIX terminology).

Use

```
$re = '/(*UTF)[^[:print:]\p{Sc}]+/';
echo preg_replace($re, '', '£aAÂ€');
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hv5p2R/2) and the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/t4lbnN).

**Details**:

- `(*UTF)` - a PCRE verb that makes PCRE engine treat the string as a Unicode string, not a byte string (note we cannot use `/u` modifier since it enables both the `(*UTF)` and `(*UCP)` verbs, the latter making all subpatterns Unicode aware and `[^[:print:]]` starts matching a lot more characters then)
- `[^[:print:]\p{Sc}]+` - matches any 1 or more symbols (due to the `+` quantifier) other than:

  - `[:print:]` - printable chars
  - `\p{Sc}` - currency symbols

Comment: I want to keep currency symbols I think that removes them?

Comment: that not what you said in your question

Comment: @user3131345: Does it mean all you need is `preg_replace('/[^[:print:]]+/', '', $str)`?

Comment: Sorry, I've not explained correctly. What I want to do is remove all non printable characters except for currency symbols. Apologies

For example £aAÂ€  to £aA€

Comment: It doesn't work in PHP when I test;

<?php
$str = '£a£AÂ£€';
$str = preg_replace('/[^[:print:]\p{Sc}]+/', '', $str);
echo ($str);
?>

Comment: Yes, I see the problem: you need to use `(*UTF)` verb. I added a PHP demo code into the answer.